# How to show pdf from a stream in Firefox 19?

Tags: firefox, pdf, outputstream

I want to ask you how can I output a pdf file from a servlet in Firefox 19.

I have a servlet that outputs a pdf stream

```
.....

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {




    try {

        String namePDF = "filename.pdf";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(request.getScheme());
        sb.append("://").append(request.getServerName());
        if (request.getServerPort() > 0) {
            sb.append(":").append(request.getServerPort());
        }
        sb.append(request.getContextPath()).append("/dirPdf/")
                .append(namePDF);

        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        Document document = new Document();
        document.setMargins(30, 30, 25, 25);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);

        PdfPageEvents events = new PdfPageEvents();
        pdfWriter.setPageEvent(events);

        // step 2: we set the ContentType and create an instance of the
        // corresponding Writer
        // writer.setEncryption(null, null, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,
        // PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_40);




        document.open();

        compiledModule(request, response, document);


        document.newPage();
        pdfWriter.setPageEmpty(false);

        // chiudo il documento
        document.close();

        int tot = pdfWriter.getPageNumber() - 1;


        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
        reader.consolidateNamedDestinations();
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader,baos);

        //read from module
        reader = new PdfReader(sb.toString());
        reader.consolidateNamedDestinations();

        PdfContentByte cbu = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(tot);
        PdfImportedPage page = pdfStamper.getImportedPage(reader, 2);

        cbu.addTemplate(page, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

        pdfStamper.close();

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(baos.size());
        response.setBufferSize(baos.size());

        baos.writeTo(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        logger.error("", e);
        try {
            /*if (out != null)
                out.close();*/
            response.sendRedirect("../exception.jsp?message="
                    + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error("", ex);
        }
    }
}

....
```

In Internet Explorer and Chrome files are viewed correctly, while in Firefox 19 I get the following error

"This PDF document might not be displayed properly"

I know there is a solution that I can achieve through changing the setting in Firefox 19, anyway since there will be many users of my application that could be discouraged by that it would be better to know if there is a practical workaround to let firefox show the pdf.

Or maybe is that a bug without workarounds?

Thank you in advance!

--- Update 28/02/2013 12:52PM ---

The problem seems to be connected with the fact that I use some ByteArrayOutputStream copy to the output stream.
If I use outputStream directly everything works fine.
Unfortunately I'm forced to use ByteArrayOutputStream since I have to paste the last page of a pdf to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my case was to change and to add a second ByteArrayOutputStream

```
.....

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {




try {

    String namePDF = "filename.pdf";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(request.getScheme());
    sb.append("://").append(request.getServerName());
    if (request.getServerPort() > 0) {
        sb.append(":").append(request.getServerPort());
    }
    sb.append(request.getContextPath()).append("/dirPdf/")
            .append(namePDF);

    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

    Document document = new Document();
    document.setMargins(30, 30, 25, 25);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);

    PdfPageEvents events = new PdfPageEvents();
    pdfWriter.setPageEvent(events);

    // step 2: we set the ContentType and create an instance of the
    // corresponding Writer
    // writer.setEncryption(null, null, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,
    // PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_40);




    document.open();

    compiledModule(request, response, document);


    document.newPage();
    pdfWriter.setPageEmpty(false);

    // chiudo il documento
    document.close();

    int tot = pdfWriter.getPageNumber() - 1;


    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
    reader.consolidateNamedDestinations();
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader,baos2);

    //read from module
    reader = new PdfReader(sb.toString());
    reader.consolidateNamedDestinations();

    PdfContentByte cbu = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(tot);
    PdfImportedPage page = pdfStamper.getImportedPage(reader, 2);

    cbu.addTemplate(page, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

    pdfStamper.close();

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(baos2.size());
    response.setBufferSize(baos2.size());

    baos2.writeTo(out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {

    logger.error("", e);
    try {
        /*if (out != null)
            out.close();*/
        response.sendRedirect("../exception.jsp?message="
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error("", ex);
    }
}
```

}

....

Looks like there are problems adding byteArrayOutputStream to himself with PdfStamper. I don't understand the connection between having only one baos and two ones. Feel free to explain...